# QML/QtQuick2 Anchor Item to static location on a scaled image

Tags: image, qml, qtquick2

What I am attempting to do is anchor an Item over a particular place over an Image.  The Image needs to use Image.PreserveAspectFit for the fillMode.  The problem I am having is that the height/width/paintedWidth/paintedHeight of the Image are for the entire image "canvas" (I'm not sure what it's actually called), not the drawn part of the image itself.  So I can't anchor to the actual image.

See code below for an example I tried with anchors (red rectangle) and with a child rectangle and x,y coordinates (green rectangle).

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

height: 400
width: 400

Image {
    id: image
    anchors.fill: parent
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    source: "image.jpg"

    Rectangle {
        id: bottomRight
        width: 40
        height: 40
        color: "green"
        x: parent.width * 0.75
        y: parent.height * 0.75
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: topLeft
    width: 40
    height: 40
    color: "red"

    anchors.top: image.top
    anchors.left: image.left
    anchors.topMargin: image.height * 0.25
    anchors.leftMargin: image.width * 0.25
    }
}
```

When you change the size of the window the placement of the rectangles is not in the same place over the image.  I'd post some screenshots but I don't have enough reputation yet!

I poked around through the widget tree using the debugger but I can't seem to find any properties that provide the information about the scaling that I could use to calculate placement of the rectangles.

***Update***
I used the following functions to calculate the margins since I will be using potentially lots of these overlays.

```
function horMargin(val)
{
    return ((image.width - image.paintedWidth)/2  + image.paintedWidth * val)
}

function verMargin(val)
{
    return ((image.height - image.paintedHeight)/2 + image.paintedHeight * val)
}
```

Comment: You should be able to post links to imgur without needing reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you *try* to use `paintedWidth` and `paintedHeight`? :)

This will give you a rectangle that fills the painted image:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    height: 400
    width: 400

    Image {
        id: image
        anchors.fill: parent
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source: "image.jpg"
    }

    Rectangle {
        x: (image.width - image.paintedWidth) / 2
        y: (image.height - image.paintedHeight) / 2
        width: image.paintedWidth
        height: image.paintedHeight
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "darkorange"
        border.width: 2
    }
}
```

From there, you can work out how to apply the margins that you need.

Comment: Okay, I see how you are doing it now.  I understand now why I was confused.  I expected the anchoring points to be to the painted image, not the image canvas.  I think your example would make more sense if you used:

    x: (image.width - image.paintedWidth) / 2
since that more closely illustrates the "problem".

Comment: Good point. The `Rectangle` could also be a child of the `Image`, depending on what your needs are.

Comment: Ya, probably equally as valid.